# Reversing a hash (finding collisions)

Tags: c++, hash, brute-force

I'm trying to find hash collisions for the following hash:

```
inline DWORD jenkins_one_at_a_time_hash(const char* value) {
    size_t len = strlen(value);
    unsigned int hash, i;
    for (hash = i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        hash += tolower(value[i]);
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    return hash;
}
```

I do not know much about algorithms, I know a hash can't be reversed but I just need an input string that returns a specific hash(does not need to be the original one).

I'm currently bruteforcing input strings but I was wondering if there is any other way that I can make the bruteforcing quicker other than calling that function with random strings.(I only need one string that matches the hash)

Comment: Trying inputs until you get your result is the definition of a brute force algorithm. You are asking if there is a quicker brute force algorithm than a brute force algorithm.

Comment: I'd recommend sitting down with pencil and paper and work through the math. That would give you an idea of where to start for writing your hash-reversing algorithm

Comment: A cryptographic hash algorithm is supposed to be collision resistant, but the algorithm must have collision if the number of inputs is larger than the number of outputs. The upper bound on this problem is sqrt(2^n). If you find a cheaper method than bruteforce, then this is not a good hashing function. Why do you need to find collisions here?

Comment: Unless a [SAT solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem) can work out the solution you're stuck doing brute force. Remember, most hashing algorithms are specifically designed to be as difficult as possible to "reverse" and find collisions. Even the weak MD5 hash is too tricky to reverse, but it's just simple enough that brute-forcing it is trivial, especially with GPU acceleration.

Comment: Most of the ops are pointless since the value is only added in once.

Comment: @tadman: jenkins is not a cryptographic hash, it is not designed to be difficult to "reverse". It is just 32-bit wide, reversing it (in the sense that find an input which hashes to a 32-bit output) is easy with using a 32-bit table.

Comment: @stark: why would it be pointless?

Comment: @geza If you have a solution, go ahead and post it. Finding collisions is probably a lot easier than in other more robust hashes, but doing this algorithmically is tricky without a solver.

Comment: A bigger problem with the 32 bit hash is that there are going to be a lot of candidates that produce the same hash once the string size is over about 6 characters. And there will be occasional, multiple inversions less than that. You will need a pretty big table to get all possible candidates for lengths over 8 increasing about 3 orders of magnitude for every 2 additional chars of candidate length.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to make brute force quicker.

1. The computation and looping over strings can be made incremental.
2. It can be made in parallel. For example, one core can check strings that start with 'a', and another with 'b', and so on. This task is highly parallelizable and running it on 1,000 processors will make it roughly 1,000 times faster.
3. Pre-compute all 2<sup>32</sup>=4,294,967,296 reversal possibilities in advance, and simply fetch the reverse Jenkins when it is needed.

The looping (option 1 in the list above) can be done by something like:

```
using text_buf_t = std::array<char, 8>;
// std::string, unlike char[], has no '\0' as the last element.
const std::string CHARS = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz[\\]^_`{|}~";

uint32_t step(char ch, uint32_t prev=0)
{
  auto hash = prev;
  hash += ch;
  hash += (hash << 10);
  hash ^= (hash >> 6);
  return hash;
}

const uint32_t finalize(uint32_t hash)
{
  hash += (hash << 3);
  hash ^= (hash >> 11);
  hash += (hash << 15);
  return hash;
}

bool brute_reverse(uint32_t target_hash, text_buf_t & buf,
                   unsigned length,
                   unsigned depth = 0, uint32_t temp_hash = 0)
{
  if (depth == length) 
  {
    auto hash = finalize(temp_hash);
    return hash == target_hash;
  }

  for (auto ch: CHARS) 
  {
    buf[depth] = ch;
    if (brute_reverse(target_hash, buf, length,
                      depth+1, step(ch, temp_hash)))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
std::string brute_reverse(uint32_t target_hash)
{
  text_buf_t buf{};
  for (int length = 0 ; length < 8 ; ++length)
  {
    if (brute_reverse(target_hash, buf, length))
      return buf.data();
  }
  return "";
}
```

Now, how bad is it? `brute_reverse(2380561940)` runs almost 10 minutes to return `" /o9c*y"`. This is the most difficult value to reverse.  Running this on 1,000 cores will make this run for 10 milliseconds. So with parallelization it sounds reasonable.

If the reversal is going to be needed frequently, then a reverse table starts to sound a very good idea. In order to check the feasibility of the reverse table its memory footprint has to be considered. The longest string that any of the 2<sup>32</sup> hashes need for reversal has 7 characters. The strings can be compressed to 5 bytes, since every character has a limited range of 69 possibilities.

Overall the table takes 5*4GB == 20 GB. For people having 32 GB RAM the reverse can reside in RAM and allow millions of hash reversals per second. My old computer has only 4 GB, so the table resides on disk. Fetching a value from a random location in the table takes around 10 millisecond, which is on par with the brute force running on 1,000 cores.

If a computer is short in RAM, the reverse table can be created in a variant of map-reduce algorithm. The algorithm loops over all strings, like the brute force algorithm, and stores string,hash pairs in 32 1.2GB files (each containing hash values with different upper bits). Once all combinations have been generated, the reduce phase converts each file to a mapping from hash->string. At no time there is a need for more than 600 MB RAM.

Here is some collision statistics (the question is titled "*Reversing a hash (finding collisions)*").

**Lengths of all 2<sup>32</sup> strings of reverse hashes**

```
len: entries    (% of total)
----------------------------
0:   1          (2.3e-08%)
1:   69         (1.6e-06%)
2:   4761       ( 0.00011%)
3:   328488     ( 0.0076%)
4:   21848661   ( 0.51%)
5:   1170033315 (27.24%)
6:   3102751727 (72.24%)
7:   274        (6.4e-06%)
```

**Run time for creating the table**: Slightly less than 2 hours on my aging laptop. It had to compute hashes for 134,039,399,920 strings due to high collision rate. Each hash was encountered 31.2085 times (around **30 collisions on average**), until the hash of `" /o9c*y"`, the biggest string was computed.

The following graph shows how many collisions (repetitions-1=collisions) there are:
[image]
This table shows that there are around 2.5*10<sup>8</sup> different hash values with collision rate of 26. Since it is hard to read low values on the Y axis, lets look at the log scale of the same graph:
[image]
There were 364 hash values that were computed only once (no collision), but this a very small minority of the 2<sup>32</sup> hash values. On the other extreme, there 86 different strings that created one hash. This is the highest collision rate during brute force reversal of Jenkins hash.

NOTES:

1. I would have put the code for creating a reverse-hash table on github, if there was no danger of flagging it as a hacking tool.
2. To calculate the collision rates in the graph I had to run the algorithm 4 times, and collect data for different hash ranges each time. A task that takes more than 2 GB RAM is very slow on my memory-deprived laptop.